# Clear text input and disable button onclick Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I have a case where I disable the submit button when entering the form and only enable it when the input box has some text.

```
<div id="app-id-input-container" ng-form="appIdInput">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input id="app-id-input" name="appIdInput" ng-click="clearAppIdInput()" class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="appId" pattern="^[AaIi][PpXxNn][0-9]{6}$" maxlength="8" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button id="addAppId" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="preferences.appIdInput.$valid && addAppId()" type="button">&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
        </span>
    </div>
    <span class="validation-alert" ng-show="appIdError">{{appIdError}}</span>
</div>
```

I clear the field when a user clicks inside the input box.

```
$scope.clearAppIdInput = function() {
    $scope.appId = "";
};
```

Even though the scope is empty, the button is not disabled.

This is how I disable the button.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#addAppId').prop('disabled',true);

    $('#app-id-input').keyup(function(){
        $('#addAppId').prop('disabled', this.value == "" ? true : false);
    });
});
```

Right now, I can disable the button again by clicking on "backspace" on my keyboard?

How do I disable the button again just when I clear the input field using a click?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following Angular way, I would recommend to use [`ngDisabled`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) directive:

```
<button ng-disabled="!appId" id="addAppId" class="btn btn-success"
        ng-click="preferences.appIdInput.$valid && addAppId()" 
        type="button">&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
</button>
```

Though the button will be disabled if `$scope.appId` is empty or undefined. No jQuery or any special handlers are needed for that.

Comment: can you pls explain your answer with  plunker example. Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1):

The field is only checking for disabling when you press a key.

You should call disable after clearing your input:

```
$scope.clearAppIdInput = function() {
    $scope.appId = "";
    $('#addAppId').prop('disabled', true);
};
```

But the answer from dhilt is more angular style and looks clearer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button id="addAppId" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="preferences.appIdInput.$valid && addAppId()" type="button">&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" ng-disabled="!appId"></span></button>
```

`ng-disabled="!appId"` will disable your button when `$scope.appId` is empty, undefined or null.

Simple snippet example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script> 
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.appId = "";
        
        $scope.clearAppId = function(){
          $scope.appId = "";
        }
    });
</script>  
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="!appId">Disable This</button>
    <input type="text" ng-click="clearAppId()" ng-model="appId"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```